# Varnish: Hiding internal backend requests

Tags: http, varnish

That is my scenario:

1) Varnish (`172.16.217.131:80`), receives a request from a client, i.e:
`http://172.16.217.131:80/a.png`

2) Request is forwarded to the Default Backend (`127.0.0.1:8000`)

3) Default backend receive the request and process it

4) That processing results in a new URL, i.e: `http://172.16.217.132:80/a.png` (**As you can see the IP has changed)

5) `172.16.217.132:80` is another backend in Varnish's config file

6) The new URL points to a resource that should be provided by Varnish
(that resource generally is an image)

My problem is: The client needs to execute 2 GETs to obtain the image.

My question:  How can I configure varnish to internally receive the
response from the first backend(`127.0.0.1:8000`), and fetch data from
the second backend (`172.16.217.132:80`), and after that, send the data
to the client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By step 4;

> 4) That processing results in a new URL, i.e:
>   `http://172.16.217.132:80/a.png` (**As you can see the IP has changed)

do you mean that it results in a HTTP Redirect? Then you could check the backend response status code in vcl_fetch (check for 301, 302 etc), use the Location header as your new url and do a restart. I found a [great example of this in the Varnish Book](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Saving_a_request.html#restart-in-vcl)

```
sub vcl_fetch {
        if (req.restarts == 0 &&
                 req.request == "GET" &&
                 beresp.status == 301) {
                set beresp.http.location = regsub(beresp.http.location,"^http://","");
                set req.http.host = regsub(beresp.http.location,"/.*$","");
                set req.url = regsub(beresp.http.location,"[^/]*","");
                return (restart);
        }
}
```